# Changing specific characters stored in an array from user input

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to create a program that has the user input a simple string of their choosing, I guess stores that data in an array and the output is changed. So if they enter "I am the very model of a modern Major General" then the program would change every instance of the letter "m" or "d" and their uppercase variant with another character. What exactly do I stick in to get the program to change what's been entered and then output the altered text?

If you can't tell I'm about five minutes new to all of this, but this one problem seems to be just out of my view. Also big sorry if I stuffed this post all up.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a new string:");
string newString = Console.ReadLine();

string[] beforeArray = { "a", "b", "d", "f", "m", "A", "B", "D", "F", "M" };    
string[] afterArray = { "!" };

Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: It's not clear what the replacement rules are here. Please show sample input and output data. What if there were more than one item in the `afterArray`? Also, why are the arrays of type `string` if they're only supposed to represent a single `char`? Do you have cases where an item the `beforeArray` would be more than one character?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please also do some basic research into the topic -- searching for "c# change string contents" brought up [this tutorial from Microsoft as the top result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/modify-string-contents).

Comment: I understand you might be new to this so here is a link you should check;

Replace a char in a string,C# Microsoft Documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but one solution could be this one:

```
void Main()
{
    var str = "I am the very model of a modern Major General";

    var toReplaceCharacters = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'm' };
    var replacementCharacter = "!";

    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (toReplaceCharacters.Contains(str.ToLower()[i]))
        {
            str = str.Remove(i, 1);
            str = str.Insert(i, replacementCharacter);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

But you should do more research in the MSDN which would answer your question a lot faster.

Comment: it's pretty clear to me the OP is asking for homework. I don't think showing the code answer right away will make OP a better coder.

Comment: In addition to @human's note, keep in mind that while it's not a problem to post answers to questions about homework, such answers should include the detailed explanation required so that the OP understands what they had wrong in the first place and why the new code addresses that.